# Want help in post message on linkedin using android

Tags: android, rest, linkedin-api

How to do comment on post/share in linkedin in android i want to put a comment on share/post which is send by user in linkedin in android? Is there any working source code available for this?

Answer (score 0):

Once you've fetched the network updates and have a particular update to comment on, all you need to do is make the following POST call:

```
POST http://api.linkedin.com/v1/people/~/network/updates/key={NETWORK UPDATE KEY}/update-comments
```

Example of a the XML input being posted:

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8'?>
<update-comment>
  <comment>I wish my company also offered skydiving classes!</comment>
</update-comment>
```

More details can be found in this document: https://developer.linkedin.com/documents/commenting-reading-comments-and-likes-network-updates