# comment on linkedin post android

Tags: android, linkedin-api

How to post comment on LinkedIn post via LinkedIn android SDK,

I tried the method from this [POST](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10894384/want-help-in-post-message-on-linkedin-using-android) but its didn't work and the doc [LINK](https://developer.linkedin.com/documents/commenting-reading-comments-and-likes-network-updates)
doesn't seems to be working. Below is the code i used to comment on a post of LinkedIn

```
        String url = "http://api.linkedin.com/v1/people/~/network/updates/key={UPDATE-KEY}/update-comments?format=json";
        String shareJsonText = "{\"update-comment\":{\"comment\":\"test comment...\"}}";

        APIHelper apiHelper = APIHelper.getInstance(getApplicationContext());
        apiHelper.postRequest(ApiActivity.this, url, shareJsonText, new ApiListener() {
        @Override
        public void onApiSuccess(ApiResponse apiResponse) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onApiError(LIApiError error) {

        }
    });
```

It gives the following error

```
exceptionMsg: java.io.IOException: No authentication challenges found

com.android.volley.NoConnectionError: java.io.IOException: No authentication challenges found
```

I have sucessfully posted on linkedIn using the below code

```
     String commentUrl = "http://" + host + "/v1/people/~/network/updates/key=";
     String shareJsonText = "{ \n" +
                    "   \"comment\":\"" + shareComment.getText() + "\"," +
                    "   \"visibility\":{ " +
                    "      \"code\":\"anyone\"" +
                    "   }," +
                    "   \"content\":{ " +
                    "      \"title\":\"Test Share Title\"," +
                    "      \"description\":\"Description text\"," +
                    "      \"submitted-url\":\"https://www.google.com\"," +
                    "      \"submitted-image-url\":\"http://www.google.com/images/logo1.png\"" +
                    "   }" +
                    "}";

    APIHelper apiHelper = APIHelper.getInstance(getApplicationContext());
    apiHelper.postRequest(ApiActivity.this, commentUrl , shareJsonText , new ApiListener() {
    @Override
    public void onApiSuccess(ApiResponse apiResponse) {

    }

    @Override
    public void onApiError(LIApiError error) {

    }
});
```

But cant figure out how to comment on a post.

---

Can anyone help me to find what i am missing to successfully commentor is their any official documentation available for posting comments cause i didn't find any on LinkedIn developer page

Answer (score 0):

looking quickly into [developer.linkedin.com](http://developer.linkedin.com) I see that

> At LinkedIn, we value the integrity and security of our members' data above all else.  In order for your applications to access LinkedIn member data and/or act on their behalf, they must be authenticated.  LinkedIn relies on the industry standard OAuth 2.0 protocol for granting access, due to its simplicity and ease of implementation.

So an authetication step should be happening before using the API.

Also, if you're not constrained to use a POST tou could use the Android SDK which I think makes everything easier. [LinkedIn Android SDK](https://developer.linkedin.com/docs/android-sdk)

As I read on I see also that

> Every API call that requires data to sent by POST or PUT has a different data structure that it expects in the payload.  Refer to the sample documentation for the specific call you are making to see the exact XML and JSON payload formats to complete your request.

Therefore make sure to provide the correct format to the JSON strings you provide.

Finally, take a look to Postman Client which is very useful when trying to perfom some HTTP work, you can get it at [Postman website](http://www.getpostman.com) usually as a Chrome app. I think that's definitely an important tool to learn!

Comment: I have used authentication as i can send a new post but didn't know how to comment on a post